# Error while creating CAR, 302 Error Found, WSO2 ESB Tooling

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb

Struggling to get passed this issue, it happens when I add my CApp to the server.

I get the error dialog, with the transport error 302 - which I'm guessing some redirect is being generated by the out of the box WSO2 ESB server....

I've dug around as much as I can - but being new to WSO2 I'm not having much luck.

The app appears in the Eclipse Servers Tab, but with a red box next to it. And all of the right click menu is greyed out except remove...

There is no .CAR in the repository. I can manually move the file there, and it appears in the admin web app.

So it seem to be a as the dialog says a transport issue....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is also having this issue:

I was able to solve this by stopping the server, restarting Eclipse / Developer Studio, removing the server from the Servers tab and adding it again. I also started running Eclipse / Developer Studio as Administrator, which may or may not be part of the solution.

Comment: Problem and resolution are still valid with Integrator 6.1.1.

Comment: It appears that this fix was, at least for me, not a long term solution. I now deploy by right clicking the carbon application in the project explorer, choosing "Export Composite Application Project" and setting the export destination to the \repository\deployment\server\carbonapps folder.